# Not able to configure Fast CGI with Apache 2.4

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php

I am trying to configure fastcgi(fcgi) on my local server .

Followed the following steps

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
apt-get install php5-cgi
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_worker
```

A wrapper /usr/local/bin/php-wrapper with the following contents :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Set desired PHP_FCGI_* environment variables.
# Example:
# PHP FastCGI processes exit after 500 requests by default.
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=10000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS

# Replace with the path to your FastCGI-enabled PHP executable
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Also included the following  in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
<Ifmodule mod_fcgid.c>
    # FCGID registers a handler named fcgid-script
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    Options +ExecCGI
    FcgidWrapper /usr/local/bin/php-fcgid-wrapper
</IfModule>
```

placed this under the vhost block and

```
<Ifmodule mod_fcgid.c>
    # Context - server config
    FcgidMaxProcesses 150
    # Otherwise php output shall be buffered
    FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
</IfModule>
```

outside the vhost block according to the tutorial

This steps were listed in the Tutorial and after completing the steps when i restart apache i get the following error :

```
[Sun Feb 14 22:52:07.754730 2016] [:crit] [pid 4125:tid 140496425252736] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information
```

I googled about this error most of them suggested `apt-get install php-cgi`
so i am not sure how to debug this issue .

apache logs show this

```
[Sun Feb 14 21:12:15.855814 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3362] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Feb 14 21:12:24.602322 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3362] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 14 21:12:29.981599 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3432] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 14 21:12:29.981673 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3432] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Can any one guide or help me as why this is happening .